# HttpClient handled differently on Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, appcelerator

I'm running through this issue since about 2 days and I can't figure out a way to solve it.
I have a service that can be called using a specific URL and sending some parameters using method POST and 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' as data type.

*This service will update a database table with a timestamp every time it is called (like 'last time logged in').*

On Android my code runs as expected, but running it on iOS (simulator) it does nothing ... Using 'Charles' I know the service is being called from both simulators but I noticed that the response takes about 60ms on iOS and about 10000ms on Android.

This is the code I use to call the service:

```
function updateUserModules(_params) {
    if(_params.Number) {
        var token = md5HashEncoder(_params.Number + '$XDTPEP132x ');
        Ti.API.warn('TOKEN: ' + token);

        var httpClient = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();

        httpClient.open("POST", "https://myxd.xdpartners.com/updateUsedModules");
        httpClient.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        var params = {
            token: token,
            licenceNumber: _params.Number,
            moduleKeyId: "71",
            terminalId: "0",
            lastUsedDate: moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
        };

        httpClient.send(params);
    }
}
```

Any ideas where the issue is?

Comment: I have done HTTP implementations to a same URL for both android and iOS, and yes, they are very different. Can you post the iOS code that wont work?

Comment: Hi Josh, what you mean the iOS code that won't work? To call the service I only use this code for both Android and iOS which is the same that works on the Android but not on iOS.

Comment: I think there is something wrong in your iOS client side code, since the service proves to run well on Android. @Luis Pedro

Comment: This is a desktop application that have some services which can be used by calling an URL with some parameters to do specific stuff, in this case is to update a record in a database. There is no client side for iOS or Android. Unless I didn't understand your post. @Josh

Comment: I thought you were writing native code for iOS (swift of ObjC), nevermind. @Luis

Comment: Sorry @Josh it's Appcelerator (Js Titanium)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is something wrong with you SSL certificate. Running your code with some adjusted params and adding an `onerror` handler gives me this output:

```
[ERROR] :  {
[ERROR] :      code = "-1202";
[ERROR] :      error = "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be \U201cmyxd.xdpartners.com\U201d which could put your confidential information at risk.";
[ERROR] :      source = "[object TiNetworkHTTPClient]";
[ERROR] :      success = 0;
[ERROR] :      type = error;
[ERROR] :  }
```

Android >5 is in some cases more forgiving, which might explain why it works there.

Comment: That's what I found too and I solve it by removing the "s" from "https". I know I removed the security but in this case I don't mins as I'm nos passing any sensible data ...

Answer (score 0):

Try `httpClient.send(JSON.stringify(params));` instead of `httpClient.send(params);`

This fixed it on my project while I was having the same issues as you.